# Vorlon.js is asking for Socket.io, but it's config is already set to include socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, vorlon

I can see the server, but when I load the app I get a red div across the front that says:

> Vorlon.js: please load socket.io before referencing vorlon.js or use includeSocketIO = true in your catalog.json file.

my terminal gives me the following output every time I load the server page:

```
{
"useSSL": false,
"SSLkey": "cert/server.key",
"SSLcert": "cert/server.crt",
"includeSocketIO": true,
"plugins": [
    { "id": "CONSOLE", "name": "Interactive Console", "panel": "bottom", "foldername": "interactiveConsole", "enabled": true },
    { "id": "DOM", "name": "Dom Explorer", "panel": "top", "foldername": "domExplorer", "enabled": true },
    { "id": "MODERNIZR", "name": "Modernizr", "panel": "bottom", "foldername": "modernizrReport", "enabled": true },
    { "id": "OBJEXPLORER", "name": "Obj. Explorer", "panel": "top", "foldername": "objectExplorer", "enabled": true },
    { "id": "XHRPANEL", "name": "XHR", "panel": "top", "foldername": "xhrPanel", "enabled": true },
    { "id": "NGINSPECTOR", "name": "Ng. Inspector", "panel": "top", "foldername": "ngInspector", "enabled": false },
    { "id": "NETWORK", "name": "Network Monitor", "panel": "top", "foldername": "networkMonitor", "enabled": true },
    { "id": "RESOURCES", "name": "Resources Explorer", "panel": "top", "foldername": "resourcesExplorer", "enabled": true }
]
```

}

(fourth line down, includeSocketIO is set to true).

Has anyone else had a similar issue (and hopefully been able to fix it)?

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. I'll let you know if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem comes from CORS errors. Socket.io doesn't have the right permission to write across domains. To fix the issue so I could open my app on my iPad, I did this:

1. Make sure the host address that you load the page from and the Vorlon script address are the same. e.g., for me, I am hitting `http://mymachine.local/...` on my iPad, and I set the Vorlon script URL to `http://mymachine.local:1337/vorlon.js` in my page. Instead of `mymachine.local`, this might be your local network IP (`192.168.x.x`).
2. I also had to load Vorlon as the first script in my page, before any other libraries.

If it's still not working, open your app in a second browser (I tested in FF with the Vorlon server open in Chrome) and check the console for CORS errors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seemed like a good idea, but I still couldn't get Vorlon working. So Firefox WebIDE can't see iOS 10 and apparently I can't get Vorlon to either. I'm hating Apple more by the minute.